# How can I configure a backup Internet connection to work instantly ? I have an adsl connection as my primary connection and a usb modem?

Tags: internet-connection

How can I configure a backup Internet connection to work instantly ?
I have an adsl connection as my primary connection and a usb modem as my second connection.

Comment: Hooked to the same PC?  What OS?

Comment: Yes to the same pc
Windows xp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the Network Binding Order so the ADSL connection is first and the USB connection follows it.  If the ADSL connection fails the PC will immediately switch to the USB connection.

1.Click Start, click Run, type ncpa.cpl , and then click OK.

You can see the available connections in the LAN and High-Speed Internet section of the Network Connections window.

2.On the Advanced menu, click Advanced Settings, and then click the Adapters and Bindings tab.

3.In the Connections area, select the connection that you want to move higher in the list. Use the arrow buttons to move the connection.

This Microsoft KB give the specific steps for how to do this.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/894564